# Cannot run an installed library

Tags: python, python-import

When I do:

```
import XYZ
XYZ.boo(xyz)
```

Where XYZ is a library and `boo` is function on that library, and xyz are the arguments I pass to the function.
I recieve an error ending with

```
AttributeError: module 'XYZ' has no attribute 'boo'
```

What is happening?

---

Note: this is intended to be the [canonical answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314500/canon-questionanswer-for-undesired-import-in-python?noredirect=1#comment293765_314500) for several questions about the same topic but with different libraries implied

Answer (score 1):

### Name your source files carefully

Make sure no Python scripts, modules, or packages in the current directory have the same name as a built-in or third-party module that you intend to import. Really it's best to avoid name conflicts altogether.

Say you want to experiment with Python's [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) module. You decided to name your script *turtle.py*, and write:

```
# turtle.py
import turtle

def move_turtle(num):
    turtle.forward(num)

move_turtle(1)
```

When you run it, you receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./turtle.py", line 2, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "/path/to/your/directory/turtle.py", line 7, in <module>
    move_turtle(1)
  File "/path/to/your/directory/turtle.py", line 5, in move_turtle
    turtle.forward(num)
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'forward'
```

The problem is your *turtle.py* is interfering with the import of the built-in *turtle* module. The statement `import turtle` actually imports your local *turtle.py* script instead of the built-in one.

There is a simple way to verify this is the problem. In the traceback, the very last file mentioned is `/path/to/your/directory/turtle.py"` which indicates you did not import the built-in *turtle* module. The built-in turtle should be located somewhere similar to `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/turtle.py` on Linux, or `C:\PythonXY\Lib\turtle.py` on Windows.

To fix this problem rename your script to something else such as `myturtle.py`.

Comment: What would happen in this case if there was a function that mimics the turtle forward action? (This is a better answer than mine, let's see if we can make it canonical)

Comment: @Llopis If the local function was named `forward()` and its arguments were similar to the actual turtle's `forward()`, you'd receive a `RecursionError`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the version of the library with such attribute.
If correctly imported you can explore the attributes with `dir(XYZ)` 
Otherwise this error is due to an undesired import.

The module python is importing
`XYZ` is one you created in the same folder or in the `%PATH` as `XYZ.py` and not the desired library. Or it is the same file where you are calling the library.

You should **rename** that module to avoid any conflict with existing packages and remove the `*.pyc` files. You could rename as `XYZ_test.py` or any other name avoiding conflicts with installed libraries.

Then you should be able to do:

```
import XYZ
foo = XYZ.boo
```

Comment: This is a very generic question, and a very generic answer (that not always is the correct answer). A quick counter-example: if an user tries to import a library `XYZ` installed through pip (version 0.1) to call a function `boo` (only available from version 0.2). They will have the same error that you mention in the question, and the solution would be to *update the library `X`*, not the one you mention.